# Modified functions.php in Magazine Pro theme of Genesis. 500 error

Tags: functions, child-theme

I made a slight change in my functions.php file, magazine pro child theme of Genesis framework. Now I'm unable to update the file and the site doesn't load. All I wanted to do was customise my site footer. This is the code I used:

```
< ?php remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'my_custom_footer' );
function my_custom_footer() {
echo'<p>&copy; Copyright 2014 <a href="http://investjunction.co.in">Invest Junction</a> | Investing made simple</p>'
}
?>
```

Comment: The opening PHP tag has a space in it. It should be: `<?php`. There should be a space after `echo`. And the echo line needs a semicolon at the end;

Comment: @NathanJohnson, put this as an answer.  You answered the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't work out exactly. I deleted the entire code for the moment and the site is back. Will keep it like that for now...!